# How to store and get List<class> in IsharedPreferences in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, list, xamarin, sharedpreferences

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.I don't know how to store List in ISharePreferences.How to implement that ?

Comment: if its a complex object, then I would agree with tiny's answer (or just use a database), but if its a list of string/int/bool/etc use something like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences ).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Gson` change  betwenn `List`<> and JsonString! Save and read `String`.